# Hp ProBook 450 G2 core i5 5th Gen vs core i7 4th Gen?

Tags: laptop

I wanted to buy a laptop for programming. 
I am a developer, I develop web and android applications. So for that I use tools like Visual Studio 2015, SQL Server, Netbeans, Android Studio, Photoshop, git, Chrome with lots of tabs opened. Most of the time I need to keep them open all the time. I am planning to buy a new laptop. I know many people will suggest I must have a SSD, but after some research I have found that I can't afford a laptop with both SSD and the configuration .

I searched and found `HP ProBook 450 G2`according to my budget but I am confused about generations. Let suppose I have these two choices..

> HP ProBook 450 G2 Core i5 5th Generation

- Hard Drive: 1TB
- RAM: 8 GB
- Graphics: 2GB dedicated

> HP ProBook 450 G2 Core i7 4th Generation

- Hard Drive: 1TB
- RAM: 8 GB
- Graphics: 2GB dedicated

  **Question:** Which one do you think is better and why? Is i7 4th generation better than i5 5th generation?

**Edit:** HERE is the link http://www8.hp.com/pk/en/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=6943826#!tab=specs

> Processor:

Intel® Core™ i7-5500U with Intel HD Graphics 5500 (2.4 GHz, up to 3 GHz with Intel Turbo Boost Technology, 4 MB cache, 2 cores)

Intel® Core™ i7-4510U with Intel HD Graphics 4400 (2 GHz, up to 3.1 GHz with Intel Turbo Boost Technology, 4 MB cache, 2 cores)

Intel® Core™ i5-5200U with Intel HD Graphics 5500 (2.2 GHz, up to 2.7 GHz with Intel Turbo Boost Technology, 3 MB cache, 2 cores)

Intel® Core™ i5-4210U with Intel HD Graphics 4400 (1.7 GHz, up to 2.7 GHz with Intel Turbo Boost Technology, 3 MB cache, 2 cores)

Intel® Core™ i3-4030U with Intel HD Graphics 4400 (1.9 GHz, 3 MB cache, 2 cores)

Intel® Core™ i3-4005U with Intel HD Graphics 4400 (1.7 GHz, 3 MB cache, 2 cores)

Intel® Celeron® 3205U with Intel HD Graphics (1.5 GHz, 2 MB cache, 2 cores)

Intel® Celeron® 2957U with Intel HD Graphics (1.4 GHz, 2 MB cache, 2 cores)

Intel® Pentium® 3805U with Intel HD Graphics (1.9 GHz, 2 MB cache, 2 cores)

Intel® Pentium® 3558U with Intel HD Graphics (1.7 GHz, 2 MB cache, 2 cores)

Comment: Please add more specs, also your question would be better worded `Which one do you think is better and why`

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/compare/87715,75121

Comment: Could you provide a link? I cannot find an HP ProBook 450G2 with an i7. The only thing I can find is i5-5200U..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will both work perfectly for you since you're focused on developping.
 the i7 4th gen is a bit of an overkill for your needs. It'd be suitable if you intend to do photo/video editing and other cpu heavy stuff.
the i5 of 4th gen and onwards will be more than enough for you needs.
the only thing to look out for is "chrome with a lots of tabs open", you're gonna need a lot of memory for that. 8gb recommended if you're the type to get more than 20tabs at the same time while using visual studios

Comment: Which one do you think is better if i installed hackintosh?

Comment: Well they both will work fine since they're both supported but in case you run into some trouble, the 4th gen will have more support due to the sheer number of adopters.

Answer (score 0):

You will get more performance from the 4th gen i7 over the 5th gen i5. But that performance comes at a price. Assuming you have the same other hardware, the 4th gen i7 will produce more heat and have shorter battery life then 5th gen i5.

5th gen i5 should have enough performance for you.